# how to change return req.user object name of passport-local?

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-passport

I'm developing a backend using nestjs and passport-local strategy. I use local strategy only for owners login in my projects. but at end of validation it returns the owner in `req.user`.

how can I change it so it returns the owner in `req.owner`?

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { OwnerService } from '../owner/owner.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private ownerService: OwnerService) {}

  async validateOwner(username: string, pass: string): Promise<any> {
    const owner = await this.ownerService.findOneByUsername(username);

    // later check with hashed pass
    if (owner && owner.owner && owner.owner.password === pass) {
      const { password, ...result } = owner.owner;
      return result;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

and

```
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable, HttpException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    super({
      usernameField: 'username',
      passwordField: 'password',
    });
  }

  async validate(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    const owner = await this.authService.validateOwner(username, password);
    if (!owner) {
      throw new HttpException('No Owner found', 404);
    }
    return owner;
  }
}
```

how I use it:

```
 @UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))
  @Post('login')
  async login(@Request() req) {
    console.log(req.owner, req.user);
    return req.owner;
  }
```

`req.owner` is empty but `req.user` has value

UPDATE:

my `Authmodule.ts`:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { OwnerModule } from '../owner/owner.module';
import { LocalStrategy } from './local.strategy';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';

@Module({
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy],
  imports: [
    OwnerModule,
    PassportModule.register({
      property: 'owner',
    })
  ],
  exports: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a LocalAuthGuard class that extends my local strategy:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class LocalAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('local') {
  constructor() {
    super({
      property: 'owner',
    });
  }
}
```

then wherever I use this guard, it adds my target field to req.owner instead of req.user.

```
  @UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
  @Post('login')
  async login(@Request() req): Promise<LoginResponse> {
    return this.authService.login(req.owner);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
PassportModule.register({ property: 'owner' })
```

where `PassportModule` is imported from `@nestjs/passport`

Comment: It didn't change anything, still getting data on req.user

Comment: I just added what you mentioned and left the rest unchanged

Comment: that should work. Here's the source: https://github.com/nestjs/passport/blob/4d2df3cad76b70ab8b43016d52d6ddf52c4ae6bd/lib/auth.guard.ts#L62

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the first entry in Google, there is also a way to dynamically change the `property`, depending on the used `LocalGuard`.

If you have multiple ways to authenticate the user, i.e., through a `user` table and an `account` table (a good approach for multi-tenant applications to separate the general users and domain users), then you need to override the `getAuthenticateOptions` in your custom `AuthGuard`.

`AccountGuestGuard`:

```ts
    @Injectable()
    export class AccountGuestGuard extends AuthGuard('account') {
      override getAuthenticateOptions(
        context: ExecutionContext
      ): IAuthModuleOptions | undefined {
        const options = super.getAuthenticateOptions(context) || {};
    
        options.property = 'account';
    
        return options;
      }
    }
```

`AccountStrategy`:

```ts
    @Injectable()
    export class AccountStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'account') {
      constructor() {
        super({
          usernameField: 'email',
          passwordField: 'password',
        });
      }
    
      async validate(email: string, password: string): Promise<Account | null> {
         // your validation logic
      }
    }
```

Just pay attention that I've added a custom name to my strategy by changing `PassportStrategy(Strategy)` to `PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'account')`. This allows me to create a custom `AuthGuard` for my `AccountStrategy` by extending it as `AuthGuard('account')`.

With this approach, I can assign my `LocalStrategy` to `req.user`, while my `AccountStrategy` is assigned to `req.account`.